# remove line from Qstring

Tags: qt

I have a QString with 5 lines

"AAAAAR"

"BBBBB"

"CCCRC"

"DDDDD"

"EEEEE"

I would like to search 'R' character only with lines from 2 to 4 If one of them contents 'R' then remove the line from my QString

I tried many method but without successs.

Comment: Show what you have tried next time...

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string for each line, giving you a `QStringList` with 5 strings in it. Then iterate from 2 to 4 and if the string contains `R`, remove the string from the string list, and in the end, join the string list back again.

```
  QString s("AAAAAR\nBBBBB\nCCCRC\nDDDDD\nEEEEE");
  QStringList l = s.split('\n');
  int i = 1, stop = 4;
  while (i < stop) {
      if (!l[i].contains('R')) ++i;
      else {
          l.removeAt(i);
          --stop;
        }
    }
  s = l.join('\n');
```

This solution should be more flexible and work regardless of the input, just select the range you want the check in.

Ironically enough, if the loop is iterated in reverse there is no problem with leaving holes and keeping track of the total count.

```
for (int i = 3; i > 0; --i) if (l[i].contains('R')) l.removeAt(i);
```

Comment: if you are calling `l.removeAt(i);` like this you will be shortening the list immediately and thus the next iteration will check `EEEEE`, not `DDDDD`. Also if you have `<3` then you actually only ever check `1` and `2` and not elements 2-4 in the list

Comment: @Erik - good point, I was still half asleep when I typed that.

Comment: the other problem I mentioned remains: you are not checking elements 2-4, but only 2 and 3 and only since you happen to remove the 3rd, you also check the fourth. If you pass `AAAAAR\nBBBBB\nDDDDD\nCCCRC\nEEEEE` as string instead of the original one, your code does not find the match when it is at the fourth position. Simply change `< 3` to `<= 3'

Comment: @Erik - nah, I don't like that because it is still tied to a static scenario and will easily result in a crash if it changes. It crashes with input string `AAAAAR\nBBRBB\nDDRDD\nCCCCC\nEEEEE`. I guess I will have to use more than a single line as much as I didn't want to :)

Comment: Could you write me How to check  if a line there is char > 'R' If yes remove the line. Each answer help me get to know QT

Comment: @Mystery - is it for capital letters only?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ddriver's solution but using iterators

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc,argv);

  QString s("AAAAAR\nBBBBB\nCCCRC\nDDDDD\nEEEEE");
  QStringList l = s.split('\n');
  for( QStringList::iterator it = ++l.begin(); it != --l.end(); ) {
    if( it->contains('R') ) {
      it = l.erase(it);
    } else {
      ++it;
    }
  }

  s = l.join("\n");
  qDebug() << l;
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
("AAAAAR", "BBBBB", "DDDDD", "EEEEE")
```

I don't use in increment in the `for` loop but instead use 
`QList::erase(iterator pos)` which `Removes the item associated with the iterator pos from the list, and returns an iterator to the next item in the list`.

I assume more generically that you want to loop from the 2nd to the second to last element, irrespective of the number of elements.

EDIT: in case you want to move a specific element in the container you could e.g. use `std::advance`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QtCore>

#include <iterator>



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc,argv);

  QString s("AAAAAR\nBBBBB\nCCCRC\nDDDDD\nEEEEE");
  QStringList l = s.split('\n');
  QStringList::iterator it = l.begin();
  QStringList::iterator itEnd = l.begin();
  std::advance(it,2); // set the number to whatever start position you want
  std::advance(itEnd,4); // set the number to whatever end position you want
  for(  ; it != itEnd ; ) {
    if( it->contains('R') ) {
      it = l.erase(it);
    } else {
      ++it;
    }
  }

  s = l.join("\n");
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The code works well but in the case there are only 5 characters.

Comment: The code works well but in the case there are only 5 lines If I have 100 lines and I want to check only lines from 30 to 50 and remove lines with Char 'R' then I cannot use  "it != --l.end(); "  Is it simple way to modify the code for more univeral.

Comment: is there a fixed scenario or do these positions change all the time? What I mean is: do you *always* have 100 elements and *always* want to search position 30 to 50 or do these things vary?

Comment: @Mystery I added another example in which you can choose the start and end position

Comment: I do not have always 100 lines   and search position is vary,

Comment: well, I can try to help, but I need to know what your follow up question is. I gave you an example how you can vary the search position. Without knowing your data, I cannot predict how the search position will change.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778705/find-max-char-in-qstringlist [/link] There is second part of my problem. I tred to modify the code myself but without success

Comment: I still do not understand. In the link you posted you seem to ask the same question only this time with removing when there is a character beyond 'F' rather than the character 'R'. What is the question that you are having? Btw, since you seem to be using the code that I posted in my answer in a follow up question, you should consider accepting the answer as it seems to have helped you solve the initial problem

Comment: I made a mess. Please an admin to delete that my question,

Comment: I made a mess. Please an admin to delete that my question, I need remove lines when there is characters hgher then definied chararacters for example 'R' or 'F' etc. It is everything what i want